# test doesn't fail when using done argument, in async function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, jestjs

Test case will automatically timeout even test supposed to failed

```
  const getAsync = async () => 1

  test("expect inside async", async (done) => {
    const a = await getAsync()
   // expect(a).toEqual(1) this will pass
    expect(a).toEqual(2)
    done()
  })
```

Expected : test failed with not equal

But , 
Result

```
    Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.
```

## Update

i guess my problem lied around the "done" argument.

When i used the done argument , the test doesn't failed 
But when i removed it , the test will fail.

but i still don't know wrong with using "done in async await?

Comment: `return new Promise` if you want to use `await`

Comment: Why do you think that `getAsync()` is actually `async`?

Comment: @Mirakurun, strictly speaking `getAsync()` does not need to be marked `async` to be `await`able. You could `await` almost anything in JS. `await` will wrap your value/express/invocation in a `Promise` for you.

Comment: @ethane from what i understand , isn't it "async" keyword will wrap the expression/value/invocation , instead of "await" key word

Comment: @JackNg, remember `await` is just syntax sugar for `then()`. Just like each `then` returns a `Promise`, so too does `await` get turned into `Promise` chains under the hood. Marking functions as `async` merely permit the usage of `await` within its function body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See also: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/3519

if you using pure async await without done, please refer @Acanthika 's anwser

if you using done :

```
  test.only("should not pass", async (done) => {
    try {
      const a = await getAsync()
      expect(a).toEqual(2)
      done()
    } catch (e) {
      // have to manually handle the failed test with "done.fail"
      done.fail(e)
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Going by [Jest documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous), this is what you have to do with async, await. Async await will always expect a return value.

```
test('expect inside async', async () => {
  expect.assertions(1);
  const a = await getAsync();
  expect(a).toEqual(2);
});
```

Or, as mentioned in documentation,

```
test('expect inside async', async () => {
  expect.assertions(1);
  await expect(getAsync()).resolves.toEqual(2);
});
```